# Combined PCA and Quantization

Tags: pca, optimization, dimensionality-reduction, linear-algebra, compression

I did some PCA on a dataset to reduce the size without compromising too much on their actual information.

However, I learnt that quantization is also an effective technique to do this. I guess it is more fine-grained and leads to compression.

Combining PCA and Quantization will hence be quite effective I guess.

I got PCA to work using Scikit learn. How do I implement Quantization? Are there any libraries or standard methods?

I am working with the Python data science stack.

Thanks for your time. I am not getting how to quantize as it doesn't seem to be a programming issue as I have to change how a number is represented.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen usage of quantization in practice, but scikit-learn has several methods that can be used as compression, and trade accuracy for memory/compute time:

- [Feature hashing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) - can be used to extract a specified number of features
- Approximate nearest neighbors with [locality sensitive hashing](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/neighbors.html#approximate-nearest-neighbors)
- [Random Trees Embedding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-trees-embedding) - partitions the data using trees and then encodes examples with appropriate indices of leaves